# What's the difference between ks test and bootstrap_p for power law fitting?

Tags: r, power-law

I want to know the goodness of fit while fitting a power law distribution in R using `poweRlaw` package. 
After `estimate_xmin()` , I had a p-value **0.04614726**. But the `bootstrap_p()` returns another p-value **0**. 
So why do these two p-value differ? And how can I judge if it is a power law distribution?
here is the plot when using poweRlaw for fitting[poweRlaw fitting result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVZ3u.jpg)

Comment: `estimate_xmin` doesn't return a p-value

Comment: then can you explain what is '$KS' value in the 'estimate_xmin' results?

Comment: See `?estimate_xmin`. It's the Kolmogorov-Smirnoff
     statistic (as described in Clauset, Shalizi, Newman (2009))

Comment: That's to say, the p-value in bootstrap_p() is the only way to see if it is a power fit?

Comment: The KS statistics helps you choose the best value of `xmin`. However, your model might still be wrong. We use bootstrapping to assess model fit.

Comment: got it! many many thanks!!

Comment: btw can I use the general ks test to assess the power fit?

Comment: No not really. I've added an answer summarising this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a bit confused. One of the statistics that `estimate_xmin` returns is the Kolmogorov-Smirnoff statistic (as described in Clauset, Shalizi, Newman (2009)). This statistic is used to estimate the best cut-off value for your model, i.e. `xmin`. However, this doesn't tell you anything about the model fit.

To assess model suitability is where the bootstrap function comes in.

Comment: I see. But I have one more question: Can I use the general **ks test** to assess the model suitability instead of `bootstrap_p`?